# Identify digital instrument or origin of samples used in "Temmie" music in "Undertale" game

Tags: vst, instruments, autotune

Where do the vocal sounds in the "Temmie Village" music track of the video game "Undertale" stem from?

Video with music: http://youtube.com/watch?v=yOD8ZZ8RTic

Can you identify whether they are from virtual instruments (which VSTs?) or are these samples, for example from VOCALOID (which voices?) or are they auto-tuned own recordings?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably vocal samples pushed thru a vocoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Temmie voices are made with the [Mixcraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixcraft) Instrument Preset “Boy Band”.

You can hear the instrument in action in [this video](http://youtu.be/qPuv8mNb_44).

Answer (score 0):

They're just normal vocal samples, likely recorded by Toby Fox himself or taken from some SNES game or sample library. They do not use any extra processing. (ex. vocoder, auto-tune)